# Inertia Heightening/Dampening Field

Tags: magic, science-fiction, physics, super-powers

So you have a Force Field around you that can Heighten/Dampen different and multiple inertia at different degrees of heighten & dampening and even negation what all can you do with it. And lets say you have a superhuman resistant grade body & can control the Force Field with your mind for ease of use.

How mush faster can you move, change direction, and other movement based things like jumping and falling?

How does this effects attacks made at you from guns, sword, & someone just punching you.

Any other things to note that you can do?

Comment: Let's say we increase the inertia of a bullet in flight - this is essentially increasing its mass. Does the bullet slow down to keep the same kinetic energy and momentum? Or does the energy/momentum just come from nowhere, and now we have a heavier bullet traveling at the same speed, with additional energy "for free"?

Answer (score 3):

Newton laws states that $F=m\cdot a$, where $m$ is the inertial mass and the proportionality factor between the applied force and the resulting acceleration.

Therefore, to answer your question, if the inertial mass is changed by a factor $k$, the acceleration resulting from the same force will be changed by a factor $1/k$. You double the inertia? The acceleration will be half. You half the inertia? The acceleration will be double.

If you can nullify/reduce the mass of an object moving toward you, you are actually reducing its energy $K=1/2 m\cdot v^2$ and momentum $P=m\cdot v$, resulting in less or no damage for you (but you need to take care of that energy and momentum somehow, if your magic is still within some science bound domain)

Comment: Thanks for the help